# Do you want hats? Winterbash 2015!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Winter Bash is back on participating Stack Exchange sites in full effect, from 14 December 2015 until 3 January 2016.

Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

So, it's time to decide if we want hats on our site. Vote on the answers below!

Comment: Yay :D Hats!!!!!!!

Comment: Okay, decision made. It is kind of obvious: we will have hats!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, I want hats! Hats are cool!

Answer (score 1):

Go away. I hate hats. I hate fun.

Comment: [I had fun once, it was awful](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/i-had-fun-once-it-was-awful-220.png)

Comment: I would have personally preferred this option to be worded less like evil, "Yes I want hats", "No I dont want hats" wouldd hae sounded perfectly nuetral ... I think its a matter of tolerance towards an alternate opinion

Comment: I get what you're saying. I chose to use "I hate hats" since that used to be the official naming of the options to turn off hats here on SE and it seems that it is also the case for this years winterbash.

Answer (score -5):

As an international community, we should recognise the fact that Christmas celebrations alone span well into January (e.g., January 7th in Russia, which is a federal holiday for Christmas Day), and Chinese New Year celebrations are in February in 2016.

Let's participate in the Winter Bash only if it spans the whole winter and does not leave anyone out.

A cut-off date of January 3rd, by the Gregorian calendar, is not inclusive and is not acceptable.

Comment: `A cut-off date of January 3rd, by the Gregorian calendar, is not inclusive and is not acceptable.` Why not? Are you really suggesting that the SE Winter Bash end-date is inconsiderate because some countries are still on holiday when the fun ends? By that logic the winter bash should start on the 24th since that's the day I officially go on holiday, and any other date would be inconsiderate towards me.

Comment: @JoErNanO, you are not precluded from participating on your winter holidays; why should others be precluded from participating on theirs?

Comment: This is best raised on meta.stackexchange - we on travel can only consider having it on our site, but we don't get to set the rules (otherwise we'd totally have hats year round!)

Comment: I don't see the connection between the winter bash and Christmas celebrations.

Comment: If *anyone* was going to have a geographical objection to Winter Bash, surely it'd be people in the Southern Hemisphere who are participating in "Winter Bash" in the middle of their summer? But I've not seen any indication that there is any such serious objection.